# Setting extent while interpolating in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, interpolation, topography

I have a set of lines representing level curves. I have also a polygon.

[image]

I want to interpolate them for creating a hypsometric map. I use the Topo to Raster command but the problem is that even if I set the extent of the map with that polygon layer, my map is created bigger. I tried to clip it but it remains the same.

[image]

I want that my map to be only as that polygon.

Is there a clipping method or a property that I can set while I interpolate the curves in order to generate a map with that extent?

Comment: Please remember to always include the version of ArcGIS that you are using within the question. Every geoprocessing command has a set of environments, which includes processing extent; you need to include this in your question as well.

Comment: Just clip it using clip_management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried this:**

1. Open Topo to Raster tool
2. Fill out all the required parameters for your project
3. Go to the '**Environments...**' button on the bottom on the tool by the Ok/Cancel buttons.
4. Ensure you have first verified the correct extent you want in the '**Processing Extent**' section. You would choose your polygon here as the extent.
5. Then, expand the '**Raster Analysis**' section.
6. Go to the part that says '**Mask**' with a drop down list right below it.
7. Select which feature you want your Topo to Raster analysis to use as a mask. I assume in your case that'd be the polygon you have, so select it.
8. Hit OK, and run Topo to Raster.

That should do the trick. If not, what I do as a backup is set my dataframe to clip to a specified shape, such as the polygon you want to clip to. Then you exclude anything in the table of contents you don't want clipped to the shape.